# How would I solve $4^{2x}=3^{x-1}+5$ analytically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I go about solving this equation:

$4^{2x}=3^{x-1}+5$

Are equations in the form
$m^u=n^v+c$ where $m,n,u,v,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ excluding trivial cases like 1 and 0
even solvable analytically? Or just numerically? Any method to get an answer without a calculator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to solve analytically such a transcendental equation; this means that you will need some numerical method.

So, consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=4^{2x}-(3^{x-1}+5)$$ As you probably noticed, it is extremely stiff which is never good for any root finding algorithm.

Consider instead
$$g(x)=\log(4^{2x})-\log(3^{x-1}+5)=4x\log(2)-\log(3^{x-1}+5)$$ which is almost a straight line.

Make a first iteration of Newton method with $x_0=0$; this will give $$x_1=\frac{16 \log \left(\frac{16}{3}\right)}{64 \log (2)-\log (3)}\approx 0.619091$$ which, looking at the graph, is probably more than sufficient for a shortcut calculation.

Anyway, you can continue iterating. I give you below (with, one purpose, a ridiculous number of figures) the Newton method iterates starting with $x_0=0$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0.619091192389461634738509980032 \\
 2 & 0.625365515837373896478065355458 \\
 3 & 0.625366440934993267336367287427 \\
 4 & 0.625366440935013449067922727304 \\
 5 & 0.625366440935013449067922727313
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this way. You can see that both functions, $f(x) = 4^{2x}$ and $g(x) = 3^{x-1}+5$ are positives, so, if you take to both sides $log_{4}$, you get

$2x = log_{4}(3^{x-1}+5)$

I am supposing that the solution is real, but, maybe, it could be an integer. Numerically it appears to be a real. I think this is a clearer way for study the equation. About your question, I don't know. I think, in some cases, you can find the solution analytically, but it depends on the integers you have. In the link below you can find information about equations very similar that the yours one.

[1]: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20Diophantine%20equation,the%20unknowns%20take%20integer%20values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20Diophantine%20equation,the%20unknowns%20take%20integer%20values))

I hope you can solve your problem!